# jQuery UI draggable can't be placed at first position in sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a draggable element that I want to drag into a sortable. However, I can't drag the draggable onto the first position in the sortable list directly. It's only possible when I move beyond the first element and then go back upwards to the position before the first element.

Have a look at this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Nh75P/53/

Please try to move the draggable directly (in one move) to the position above 'Sortable 1'.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've seen this all over the web. I think it's by design. Is it really a problem?

Comment: Yes, in our case it is really important. In the official demo it seems to work, too. Please have a look here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#sortable

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with sortable. Apparently on enter the offset of the entry is not accounted for. Submit a bug about this [here](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Thank 'Nick Melville' on https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-1-8rc1-sortable-list-doesn-t-allow-drop-at-first-and-last-position-depending-where-the-mouse-gets-clicked-to-drag-on for his answer:

> Since this is still a high search result page...  Changing the
> tolerance to 'pointer' should resolve this issue for you:
>
> http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-tolerance